# What is the lift coefficient of human body?

Tags: classical-mechanics, everyday-life, aerodynamics, bernoulli-equation, lift

Assuming  we can change angle of attack by changing our hands orientation what is the maximum aerodynamic lift coefficient of human body?

Comment: Hi, welcome to PSE. You would expected to show what research you have done yourself on this question. There are many variables involved, for example you would need to give an idea of what position the rest of the body adopts, different body shapes would be affected differently.

Comment: @studystudy I would like to know about any data available on lift coefficient of human body.  Lets say a man is sitting on bike (let's say behind the driver and not driving it) ,so I want to know at what speed should bike move (neglecting wind speed in ground frame) so that the person whose both hands are at 45degree to horizontal.(I am unconcerned about effects if drag etc) .I know lift would be qsC where C is lift coefficient which I need.

Comment: If you search for  "EURECA 2013 - Calculation of Aerodynamic Drag of Human Being in Various Positions" you will find a short pdf related to your question. But, at the risk of offending you, you need to search yourself and then come back with your question altered to reflect your reading papers such as the above.

Comment: Another possible source: olympic ski jumpers need to know this information.  A Google search of this subject will probably turn up a lot of information.